# OpenAlex Institution ID No Found Question

Tags: python, json, pandas

I am trying to get the count of works with concepts level =0 and citation count >5 over the year starting from 1980 till now. I have found the concepts_ids that their level is 0 and stored in a list. I stored the result to csv file, and I tried two institutions, Keio University and Waseda University, but there are not match records in the csv file. I manually used the API on their website, and I am pretty sure these two schools must have papers meeting the requirements. So, I am just wondering which part did I miss?

```
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd


year_range = range(1980, 2024)
year_list = list(year_range)
concepts_ids = {'C127313418', 'C17744445', 'C121332964', 'C41008148', 'C144024400', 'C33923547', 'C138885662', 'C185592680', 'C15744967', 'C127413603', 'C142362112', 'C95457728', 'C205649164', 'C39432304', 'C144133560', 'C162324750', 'C71924100', 'C192562407', 'C86803240'}

# Lists to store data
concept_id_list = []
year_list_result = []
institution_list = []
count_list = []
institution_name = []
for concept_id in concepts_ids:
    for year in year_list:

        api_url = f'https://api.openalex.org/works?filter=publication_year:{year},cited_by_count:%3E5,concepts.id:{concept_id}&group_by=authorships.institutions.lineage'


        response = requests.get(api_url)


        json_data = response.json()

        # Extract relevant information
        for entry in json_data.get('group_by', []):
            concept_id_list.append(concept_id)
            year_list_result.append(year)
            institution_list.append(entry.get('key'))
            count_list.append(entry.get('count'))
            institution_name.append(entry.get('key_display_name'))

# Create a DataFrame
result_df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'concept_id': concept_id_list,
    'year': year_list_result,
    'institution': institution_list,
    'count': count_list,
    'institution_name' : institution_name})

# Display the DataFrame
print(result_df1)
```

Comment: This search will only find the first 200 results for each year and concept. Have you tried using [paging](https://docs.openalex.org/how-to-use-the-api/get-lists-of-entities/paging) to get more results past the first 200?

Comment: Basic paging does not seem to work on a group by query, but cursor paging seems to work.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I know the limit of paging, so that's why I used a loop to loop through every year and the concepts_id, I got 167200 rows from the output, I just could not find those two universities that I mentioned in the post.

Comment: It might be that those two universities are not in the top 200 of citations for any combination of concept or year.